# Book about magical wax and twins

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book a while ago about these two gloomy looking twins that lived alone in a mansion and it was built above a pool of this white wax/liquid. It had special properties and there was different waxes around the world, I can't seem to remember what it was called though, there were multiple books.